# Jersey 2.2.0 on Google App Engine. Error 404. jersey init. works locally though

Tags: google-app-engine, jersey

I am deploying my app using jersey 2.2.0 jars onto google app engine. I have been developing and running locally and it works well during local run/test.

I deployed to the google app engine, and I start getting Error: 404 erros for all resources. Checking google logs, at the first request it spits out the following

> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler initialize: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.7 2014-03-12 18:11:31...

The jersey servlet spits out the following

> I 09:27:38.889 org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log: 1 * Server has received a request on thread Request EE25C261
>   GET http://xxxx.appspot.com/service/users/test
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
>   Host: xxxxx.appspot.com
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36
>   X-AppEngine-City: bangalore
>   X-AppEngine-CityLatLong: 12.971599,77.594563
>   X-AppEngine-Country: IN
>   X-AppEngine-Region: ka

and then spits out the resource not found

> I 09:41:15.094 org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log: 3 * Server responded with a response on thread Request 9826AB68
>    < 404

It also adds one more line which suggests

> I 09:27:39.180 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.

Now, all this works on my local testing but is only an issue when deployed to Google App Engine.

Here's my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
      </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
<!--           Enter your Jersey resources to speed up initial Jersey loading
          You can separate the java packages using , -->
          <param-value>com.poolE.web.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
    </system-properties>
</web-app>
```

and my jersey class is

```
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.poole.web.jpa.EMFService;
import com.poole.web.jpa.Users;
import com.poole.web.jpa.model.User;

@Path("/users/")
public class UsersResource {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UsersResource.class.getName());

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("test")
    public String info() {
        log.info("comes into test");
        return "Hello Jersey on Google App Engine";
    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated. I am stuck in this frustrating problem of just plumbing it all together in GAE

Comment: I know nothing about jersey and how it path matches. But my guess is `@Path("/users/")` won't match `http://xxxx.appspot.com/service/users/test` - specifically "test" have you tried `"/service/users/"` everything else looks correct.  What I mean is all the log messages look correct.

Comment: But `info()` method is annotated with `@Path("test")` so it looks fine.

Comment: thanks for looking into this. as i tried to mention above .. it works fine on my local. this is something to do with the google app engine production environment.. jersey is not able to look up the configured web resources in that environment while it works in the local app engine build environment

Comment: Anything works fine on GAE env? E.g. index.html site?

Comment: I downgraded to jersey 1.18 to solve the issue. there was some issue after that as well, so had to create an Application class to register my jersey resources

Comment: @NikunjManocha how do you create an application class to register jersey resources?